# Try to decipher this puzzle; It's cipher is historical

Tags: knowledge, cipher

**A individual known for Polygraphiae...**

Gpqg atxr bqocq, ucl tzv rip gkmv iu ydw ynpa nkdk?
Gvxi jamy dj przcl Gagmguon sd droabp, jxughv rge cgvx!
Luvl fycw!

Comment: Thanks for all the help/edits -  feel free to edit all my questions/post(s) just wanted to say this so everyone know.  //You now must (**MUST**) have  A CORONA FREE year!  //Wishes Will

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Plaintext:

> Good work there, how did you know it was this easy? This site in stack Exchange is really, really the best! Good work!

Method:

> Ascending [Trithemius Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_recta) with no initial shift

Comment: Really, My gosh. Good work there!  You make this look so easy!  Ill accept your answer when I can (time limit is 12 mins)  :)